# Vim not colouring the end of lines when run inside screen

Tags: vim, colors, gnu-screen

When vim is started inside of gnu screen it does not colour the background after text.

[image: White background]

Screen looks like it should be setup for handling 256 colours correctly:

```
$ screen
$ tput colors
256
$ echo $term
xterm-256colors
```

OS & Shell I am using:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux WS release 4 (Nahant Update 9)
$echo $shell
/bin/tcsh
```

The Colour test looks like it is working ok except the end of lines:

```
:runtime syntax/colortest.vim
:source %
```

[image: vim colour test inside screen]

And when not using screen:

[image: vim colour test]

Is there any other settings I should be checking, is there a screen mode I can force to allow the colours to be redrawn correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partly based on: [tmux-and-screen-256-term-not-supported](https://superuser.com/a/431926/42141).

The issue resolves itself when using a 'screen' term. To identify as 256 colors correctly it should be 'screen-256colors'. Which leads to the error below :

```
E558: Terminal entry not found in terminfo
'screen-256colors' not known. Available builtin terminals are:
    builtin_gui
    builtin_ansi
    builtin_xterm
    builtin_iris-ansi
    builtin_d
```

To create a screen-256colors entry:

```
infocmp screen > screen-256color.ti
```

Changing (screen-256color.ti)

```
#       Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /usr/share/terminfo/s/screen
screen|VT 100/ANSI X3.64 virtual terminal, 
        am, km, mir, msgr, xenl, 
        colors#8, cols#80, it#8, lines#24, ncv#3, pairs#64,
```

to :

```
#       Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /usr/share/terminfo/s/screen
screen-256color|VT 100/ANSI X3.64 virtual terminal, 
        am, km, mir, msgr, xenl, 
        colors#256, cols#80, it#8, lines#24, ncv#3, pairs#64,
```

Now create the terminfo :

```
tic screen-256color.ti
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside `screen` or `tmux`, the value of `$TERM` needs to begin with `screen` (e.g. `screen`, `screen-256color`) rather than with `xterm`.

The current issue appears due to the difference in the `bce` (background color erase) capability of the two terminals.

The `TERM=screen*` descriptions do not contain this flag, and accordingly, in `screen` or `tmux` a "clear from the cursor to the end of the line" escape sequence paints that with the terminal's default background color.

On the other hand, `TERM=xterm*` descriptions do contain this flag, and accordingly, `xterm` erases using the currently active background color.

In your case, `vim` incorrectly sees that the terminal has the `bce` flag (because of `TERM=xterm*`) and so uses the shorthand clear operation to fill with the currently active background color, which would appear correctly directly under xterm, but appears incorrectly under `screen`/`tmux`. If you correctly give it `TERM=screen*` then it will notice the lack of `bce` and will choose to emit plenty of space characters rather than the "clear to the end of the line" sequence, which will look correctly.